# React-native wont build after upgrading react-native-firebase from v5 to v6

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

In Xcode, I get the following error during *archiving*

```
Showing All Messages
: Directory not found for option '-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mobile-ffdrrqgiyphlinerkjxrqqqeocrs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Mobile/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React'

ld: library not found for -lRNFirebase
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get this error when I try to archive it.

When I try to build it using the command 
`$ react-native run-ios`
in the terminal (with `$ react-native start` to run metro bundler), I get:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Mobile.xcworkspace
```

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Mobile/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mobile.app/UmappedMobile normal x86_64
(1 failure)
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '10.3'

target 'Mobile' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  libPath = '..'
  nodeModules = "#{libPath}/node_modules"
  rn_path = "#{nodeModules}/react-native"

  # Pods for Mobile

  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
  ]

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'
  pod 'RNFBDatabase', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database'
  pod 'RNFBAuth', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end
end
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^8.0.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^7.2.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    ...
  }
```

I've tried clearing my node_modules and Pods folder within ios. Been trying to debug this for a while, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I would recommend that:

- Delete the package-lock.json, and do an npm install
- Considering that these firebase packages have the auto-link feature, perform a pod install previously deleting the Podfile.lock.
- In the xcode, carry out the Clean Build Folder.
- Perform the build

Comment: I just read again, and I see a few unusual things:
1.- In Podfile, it is not normal to add the new libraries above the react implementations. It is recommended that they always be down, at least in your case, after the 'Folly' pod.
2.- You have installed firebase v6, whose version is recommended only for versions of react native 0.60 onwards.
For that version of react native, install version v5.

Comment: v6 is fine for 0.59.10 and v5 has a library that is deprecated (UIWebView). I did restart my computer and now I'm getting ` Directory not found for option '-L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mobile-ffdrrqgiyphlinerkjxrqqqeocrs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Mobile/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React'`

Comment: ok I downgraded my firebase to v5 but with a higher minor version and cleared the cache of my react-native app. Also had to modify an import statement inside the iOS code and it now compiles.